# Understanding AWS route-tables - cannot create a more specific route

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-vpc, routetable

I wish to make my VPCs subnets accessible from the Internet.

More specifically: traffic from the Internet Gateway (igw-f43c4690) to my subnets must be allowed.

For that I created a Route Table and associated it with my subnets.

[image]

**Question:**

I understand the traffic will be redirected from the Internet Gateway (Target) to the IP range (Destination) - right?

Why must I name a more generic ip range here (`0.0.0.0/0` in pic above), than mentioned in the local route?

Why can't I name an IP range, the same as in my subnet, here and then associate the route table with my subnet?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of the Route Table as defining where traffic goes **when it leaves the subnet**. If an Amazon EC2 instance on a subnet wishes to send traffic to a destination on the Internet, the Route Table tells it to go via the Internet Gateway.

The Route Table also controls whether a subnet can **receive** traffic from the Internet, but it is defined with **outgoing** rules. That's why the column is called **Destination**.

Traffic going out of a subnet is evaluated against all the rules in the Route Table, starting with the smallest range of addresses through to the largest range (which is `0.0.0.0/0`). Thus, traffic can be routed through a Virtual Private Gateway, VPC Peering, NAT Gateway, and so on, before it is finally routed to the Internet as a 'catch-all' setting.

**Bottom line:** Define your outgoing routes and the in-going routes will work just fine.

Comment: THnx for replying. So `Target` tells me where the traffic goes when leaving the subnet, and `Destination` tells me from where I can receive traffic? Im not getting why receiving is defined with outgoing rules. Outgoing is for me the same as leaving?

Comment: You are defining rules for how traffic leaves the subnet. Traffic destined for the **Destination** will be sent to the **Target**. Incoming traffic magically works in the reverse -- just don't think about it.